# Android: Contact photo is pixelated while trying to set into an ImageView

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

Am trying to fetch phone contacts image and set into an ImageView . Am getting the image, but when I try to set the image into an ImageView it is pixelated.

**The code for fetching the image**

```
    String select = "(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " == \"" + name + "\" )";
        Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
        startManagingCursor(c);

        if (c.moveToNext()) {
             idValue = c.getString(0);
        InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                            ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(idValue)));

  if (inputStream != null) {
      photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
      contact_image.setImageBitmap(photo);
     }
   }
```

I want to show the details of contacts , Because of that i try fetch the Contact ID by name.

**Layout.xml**

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contact_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/un_known_avtar" />
```

[image]
I try almost all scale type by xml. But still the contact image is stretchered.

Can any one please help to avoid the stretching of Contact Image

Comment: can you add screenshot?

Comment: @ Awais King  i just add screentshot , can you please check

Comment: It is because some low-end Android devices save contact's image in low resolution because of RAM, so when you try to stretch it after retrieving the image will have lots of noise at edges or become blurry

Comment: No, I am using Xiamoi, it have 1 GB ram and running 4.4 version. In default calling screen that contact photo is shown in the calling background and it is not pixelated. Just now I try to set image into the imageView from galley.At that time also the image is not pixelated. When i try to fecth image from contact by isung conatct id at that time only the image is pixelated  @ Awais King

Comment: did you capture contact's picture with same device, or it was already set?

Comment: yes, I captured the picture with same device @ Awais King

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding **true** boolean at end of `openContactPhotoInputStream` for high resolution *(NEEDS API LEVEL 14 OR HIGHER)*

```
InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(idValue)), true);
```

Source: [Large Photo Version from contacts in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368289/large-photo-version-from-contacts-in-android)

Comment: Thanks , what should we do for lower version @Awais King

Comment: I don't think you can do it in lower APIs because `Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO` is only available in 14+ APIs

Comment: Ok Thanks  @ Awais King